# convert nested array to nested obj in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the nested array to nested obj:
For ex,

```
let ip_array = [
                 ["fdsfasdf","hghfhgh"],
                 ["fsdf","hjghhjhj"],
                 ["fdfss","hjghh"]
               ]
```

expected o/p :

```
let new_array = [
                  {"fsdfdsf":""fgdfgdfg},
                  {"dfdsd":"jhjghj"},
                  {"dfsddfds":"hghfh"}
                ]
```

Comment: What? `let ip_array = [["fdsfasdf": obj],["fsdf":obj],["fdfss":obj]]` isn't even valid JavaScript. Did you test this?

Comment: edited question

Comment: There is still a glaring syntax error in your expected output (`""fgdfgdfg`). Please read and double-check before posting.

Comment: Your output and input don't have obvious relationship with each other. You just typed a bunch of random letters. For example, in your input `"fdfss"` is there at the end, and that doesn't appear anywhere in your expected output

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with JavaScript's [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

First, you use `Array.map()` to iterate through the input array, and return the result by using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to set the key/property of each object.

```js
const arr = [["fdsfasdf","hghfhgh"],["fsdf","hjghhjhj"],["fdfss","hjghh"]];

const res = arr.map(element => {
  return {
    [element[0]]: element[1]
  };
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
let ip_array = [["fdsfasdf","hghfhgh"],["fsdf","hjghhjhj"],["fdfss","hjghh"]]
let myObj    = ip_array.map((a, k) => {

                   return { [a[0]]: a[1] };
               })
```

Comment: hmmmm... why did this got a -1 and the other answer +1 ? only for the parameters (a,k) ???

Comment: @Eli Well, I"ve no idea

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using the newer [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method.

**Caution:** This is very new method and is still in draft specification at the time of writing this answer in 2019. It may not be cross-browser compatible.

```js
let ip_array = [
                 ["fdsfasdf","hghfhgh"],
                 ["fsdf","hjghhjhj"],
                 ["fdfss","hjghh"]
               ]

let new_array = ip_array.map((arr)=> Object.fromEntries([arr]));

console.log(new_array);
```